# What are the hundred mistakes of shishupal in Mahabharata?

Tags: scripture, mahabharata, krishna, arjuna, yudhisthira

In Mahabharata what were the **hundred mistakes** of **shishupal** ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.